# Convolution of Heaviside distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

The convolution of two heaviside distributions from $$D'(\mathbb{R}^2)$$ is given to be
$$ H(t-|x|)*H(t-|x|)=H(t-|x|)(t^2-x^2)/2$$

Writing out the definition using integrals isn't really helping to get the $$(t^2-x^2)/2$$ term.

How can this possibly be done?

Comment: Do you know how convolution of distributions is defined?

Comment: Yes, <f*g,ф>=<f(x),<g(y),ф(x+y)>>

Comment: Is the convolution to be done in the $x$ variable?

Comment: The variable is t-|x|. As in f(X) here is H(t-|x|). Ф(Х+Y) = ф(x+y,t+т). X=(x,t), Y=(t,т).

Comment: Thus, each <•,•> is a double integral.

Comment: Ah, so $x$ is 1-dimensional? I thought that $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $|x| = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$.

Comment: $x$ is 1-dimensional but ф is two dimensional. Also, $H$ is a function of two variables $x$ and $t$.

Comment: So if we set $u(t,x)=H(t-|x|)$ then we want to calculate $u*u$ where the convolution is taken over both variables?

Comment: Yes, treating the convolution as a functional acting on $\phi(x,t)$.